# Regex: Match all words that do not contain hyphen

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, expression, regex-lookarounds

Here is what I have so far :

`\b(?<!-)\w+(?!-)\b`

Matches inline words that do *not* contain hyphens.

Question:

Is there a clever way to do the above but without using a *negative lookbehind*?
(clever being optional)

Comment: Use a capture group to extract the word and an alternation to describe the possible content before: `(?:^|[^-\w])(\w+)\b(?!-)`. If your pattern is for a replacement, change the non-capturing group to a capture group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you want to match `[^-]\b(\w+)\b[^-]` - a word not adjacent to hyphens. This would work great, but since it matches the word boundaries, it consumes them, and skips every other word because the following word can't match a leading boundary.  (It also doesn't match line endings or beginnings, solved by non-capturing groups with alternatives: `(?:[^-]|^)\b(\w+)\b(?:[^-]|$)`.)

You need information about the word boundary without consuming the character. You could get non-consumption from a lookahead or lookbehind: `(?:[^-]|^)\b(\w+)\b(?=[^-]|$)` matches your words.  This doesn't fit the problem statement.

Seems to me like you'd have to write code to get non-consumption without a look-ahead/-behind.  RegExp objects store the index of the last consumed character, so we can "unconsume" a character by fiddling with it a bit.

```
function getAllWords(str) {
    let pat = /(?:[^-]|^)\b(\w+)\b(?:[^-]|$)/g;
    let res;
    let words = [];
    while (res = pat.exec(str)) {
        words.push(res[1]);
        pat.lastIndex--; //unconsume the word boundary so it can be matched again
    }
    return words;
}
```

Since the lookahead simplifies all this a lot, and stops you from fiddling with object internals, I'd really recommend just using a lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only need an alternative for the negative lookbehind, because it has very little browser support.Since the solution isn' as straightforward, I'm thinking that doing a simple filter loop will suffice: `var result = str.split(' ').filter(f => f.indexOf('-') == -1);`